# Navigation destination is not a direct child of this NavGraph

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I just passed new variable in navigation graph while opening a new screen and **android tests** start failing with the error that destination is not a direct child of this NavGraph. I updated graph as:

**NavHostProvider.kt**

```
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination.screenName) {
composable(Screens.BREAKDOWNSUMMARY.screenName + "/{Id}") {
            val breakdownSummaryViewModel: BreakdownSummaryViewModel =
                hiltViewModel()
            breakdownSummaryViewModel.uiState.value.uldId =
                it.arguments?.getString("Id").toString()
            val Id = it.arguments?.getString("Id")
            if (!Id.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                BreakdownSummaryScreen(
                    navController,
                    breakdownSummaryViewModel,
                    headerViewModel,
                    lightHeaderViewModel,
                    Id
                )
            }
        }
```

**BreakdownSummaryViewModel.kt**

```
  @Before
fun launchComposable() {
    lightHeaderDataSource.addLightInfoToHeader("DL0558", "15", "06JUN2023")
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHostProvider.ArrivalsNavHostApp(
            navController,
            startDestination = Screens.BREAKDOWNSUMMARY
        )
        navController.navigate(Screens.BREAKDOWNSUMMARY.screenName + "/${Id}")
    }
}
```

Kindly help me resolve the problem if you get it. Thanks in advance.

**Note: App works fine, just test fails.**

Comment: This doesn't depend on viewModel, but we have something to do with the NavigationGraph configuration and how we pass the parameters, can you try using Query parameters instead of Path parameters

Comment: I shared the test file of ViewModel where it's showing the error.

Comment: Let me check it, is it failing while running the app on device or just ui tests?

Comment: UI test gets failed. App works fine